# How to make page-break work with flexbox?

Tags: css

I have an HTML structure as follows:

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.item {
height: 500px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.item:nth-child(1){
background: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(2){
background: green;
}
.item:nth-child(3){
background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(4){
background: yellow;
}
.item:nth-child(5){
background: orange;
}
.item:nth-child(6){
background: violet;
}
 @media print {
 .item{
  page-break-before: always;
 }
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="item" style="order: 4;">Four</div>
<div class="item" style="order: 3;">Three</div>
<div class="item" style="order: 5;">Five</div>
<div class="item" style="order: 2;">Two</div>
<div class="item" style="order: 0;">Zero</div>
<div class="item" style="order: 1;">One</div>
</div>
```

The order is being set from javascript based on some conditions. I would like the page to be printed where each div.item starting on different pages.

```css
@media print {
.item{
   page-break-before: always;
}
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this as pagebreak won't work with flexbox and I need to keep the order in which the items are printed on page.

Answer (score 0):

this code doesn't solve the problem to the end, but it can give you new ideas on how to use it in your project

```js
    function printdiv(printpage) {
      var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
      var footstr = "</body>";
      var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
      var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
      document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
      window.print();
      document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
      return false;
    }
```

```html
  //HTML Page //Other content you wouldn't like to print
  <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt" onClick="printdiv('div_print');" value=" Print ">

  <div id="div_print">
    <h1 style="Color:Red">The Div content which you want to print</h1>
  </div>
  //Other content you wouldn't like to print //Other content you wouldn't like to print
```

plugin helps to print different divs [github](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis)